# a question on the Poincar\'e bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

Let $C$, a smooth curve. Let $J$ its Jacobian, consider the Poincar\'e bundle $\mathcal{P}$ on $J\times J$. Let $p: J\times J\rightarrow J$ the projection. 
How can I compute the complex $R p_{*} \mathcal{P}$ in a point $L\in J$, i.e. what is explicitily

$$
R p_{*} \mathcal{P}_{L}
$$

Comment: There is more than one projection.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63939/a-question-on-the-poincare-bundle